# How do I read Ordinate values from Oracle Spatial that won't fit in a .NET Decimal Type?

Tags: c#, oracle, overflow, odp.net, spatial

I am trying to read Oracle Spatial data with C# using ODP.NET.

In some cases, my Oracle Spatial data has Number values in the SDO_GEOMETRY’s OrdinateArray that are too big for .NET to handle.  So, when I try to read the SDO_GEOMETRY values, it throws a “System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow”.   In my case, the ordinate values just have too many digits after the decimal point, and I don’t care about losing this information.

My code is based on the sample app here:  http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/27794/296419/0/#msg_296419

I see there are SafeMapping approaches with DataSets to read Number types that won’t fit into Decimal types, but I don’t see how to apply this to an internal part of the SDO_GEOMETRY type.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Here is the Oracle definition: `CREATE TYPE sdo_ordinate_array AS VARRAY (1048576) of NUMBER;`

Answer (score 0):

What is the Oracle Datatype of "OrdinateArray"? If it is a user defined type (eg VARRAY), you can create a custom .NET class to accept the data. For more information on this, read up on "User Defined Types"

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for you but maybe someone could use my solution to the problem.

I run into this problem while making custom shapefile to Oracle Locator importer in C#.

What I did is I changed ordinatesArray variable type from decimal[] to double[] in SdoGeometry class. Same change (decimal to double)was needed for

public class OrdinatesArrayFactory : OracleArrayTypeFactoryBase {}

and

OrdinatesArray = GetValue((int)OracleObjectColumns.SDO_ORDINATES) in MapToCustomObject method.

In fact the code was working OK with decimal type when I imported data using oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature tool.
Problems started when I imported data using my tool (shapefile geometry to WKB and then insert to Oracle using 
INSERT INTO some_table (GEOM) VALUES (SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY())
For some reason ordinates where too big for decimal although I handled precision.